# Can't add anchor constraints to View of TableCell anymore

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, anchor

I updated my Xcode to develop for 14.5 (from 13.5) and my View into `TableCell` no longer wants to resize.

Here is the code that worked before:

```
commandeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        commandeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 60), // 20
        commandeView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -60), // -10
        commandeView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 40), // 10
        commandeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

`commandeView` is the view that is natively in a `Cell`.

Even with the constraints, the view takes up all the space in the cell.

Does someone have some ideas?

Comment: Would you like to provide any screenshot about what is your current app behave and screenshot of how it should look like?

Comment: Make sure you work with the cell's `contentView` ... you should have `contentView.addSubview(commandeView)` and then your constraints should be `equalTo: contentView.topAnchor` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
commandeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.addSubview(commandeView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    commandeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 60), // 20
    commandeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -60), // -10
    commandeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 40), // 10
    commandeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
])
```